# Installing PHP, Apache 2.2.10 on Windows Vista

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to get PHP working on my vista home machine but I am getting weird problems. First I had file permission problems for which I disabled Vista's UAC. Now I can't get the PHP interpreter working.

I have made all the necessary changes following some tutorial but I still can't get it working.

Tutorial was located here: http://www.tanguay.info/wamp/installPhp5.php5

Comment: Why disable UAC just for permission problems in Apache? Just give apache proper permissions to files in the installation folder (e.g. logs)

Answer (score 4):

Try [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). I use that at home on a Vista machine and it worked nicely after the install.

Comment: that was really fast ...thanks...been trying this for almost a day....If  XAMPP works ... I dont have words to express my gratiture....thanks

Comment: Defiantly, either that or WAMP if you have no need for Pearl.

Comment: it did work...though took me a while to get a IDE for PHP too...but thanks a tonne...i really appriciate it

Answer (score 2):

[WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com/) is also a good option. You can easily enable/disable both PHP extensions and Apache 2 modules. Everything is set up somewhat securely (only local access to the serve), and you get phpMyAdmin already set up.

Only thing I've ever missed is Memcached, but that is fairly easy to set up on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I have installing PHP and Apache on Vista is that you need to make sure that when you edit the httpd.conf that you are editing it as an admin, otherwise the file is saved in compatibility mode.

To overcome that problem just type notepad++ or whatever in your start menu, right click the item and run as administrator. Then open the file from the app.

Answer (score -1):

You can use FastCGI for IIS 7. I'm using this also and it works perfectly!!

[FastCGI](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-70/)

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Zend Core](http://www.zend.com/en/products/core/downloads)

It works on both IIS and Apache (it includes the installation of the Apache)

Answer (score -4):

iis7 is one of the best web servers and especially for php, if you can't get it to work it means you need to google enough, because it isn't logical to blame Vista for php/apache issues

Comment: i was not blaming microsoft...i have great respect for some of the products that they have developed...its just that vista is a little difficult to work with..as a developer...i had to turn off UAC to actually get things working for me...

Comment: I have a problem with "iis7 is one of the best web servers and especially for php". Unfounded?